# Rewrite url from parameter into subdir

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url

As search by parameters, I want url display subdir instead parameter like this:

Here params url : `search/?genre=a&pref=b&city=c&sticking&=d`

And here is subdir url after convert for display: `search/a/b/c/d`

In the case search url has less than 4 params, it can be converted to some urls like this:

```
search/a/b/c
search/b/c/d
search/a
search/b
...
```

Is there any way to use htaccess to do that?

I'm using Laravel.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: can you post your route?

Answer (score 2):

In your /route/web.php or /route/api.php file, you can define the route like below:

```
Route::get('/search/{a?}/{b?}/{c?}/{d?}', 'SearchController@method');
```

In the controller as suggested by Rian Zaman, you have to do something like this:

```
public function method_name($a = null, $b = null, $c = null, $d = null)
{
    // Your code here ...
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put initial brace at `b?}`

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Thank you for your suggest. Since url has no genre like that 
search/pref/city/sticking
How can I know it is pref/city/sticking? It means I need to get which belong to for searching in database

Comment: using params will tell me which param is. search/?genre=a&pref=b&city=c&sticking&=d. So it is the reason why I want use param and rewrite url

Comment: @HaiTien, That's easy to tackle using the order sequence. In case any or many of the params happen to be null, you can put null in the query string like: search/book/null/1/null

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Since my customer do not like adding null to url, we cannot use this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve that I would suggest to use optional route parameters if you know what could be the max number of search term.

You can achieve that by doing the following,

In your route:

`Route::get('/your-route/{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}/{param4?}');`

In your controller:

```
public function function_name($param1 = null, $param2 = null, $param3 = null, $param4 = null){
// your logic
}
```

Please follow the link for reference: [Optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Comment: thank you so much. let me try with your suggestion